# Ошибка отступов на Python

Tags: python

Пытаюсь написать программу для ИИ. В строке 116 выдаёт ошибку с отступами, пробовал всё - не помогает. Прошу неговорить мне о других ошибках.
(Строка 116 - перед строкой Print('Cant walk!!!'))

Код:
https://pastebin.com/vBaNJg2F

Ошибка:
https://pastebin.com/SVGRptZS

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

```
        else:
            try:
                if dir == 'R':
                    ...
                else:
                    return
# А КТО БУДЕТ ДЕЛАТЬ ПОСЛЕ try except?!!!

    else:
        print('Can walk!!!')
        self.death()
```

У вас в коде на 108 стоке есть `try`, но нигде нет `except`

Т.е. вы отслеживаете ситуацию, но исключение не выбрасываете если что, а так нельзя

Допишите свой код:

```
        else:
            try:
                if dir == 'R':
                    ...
                else:
                    return
            except:
                # что-то делаем, например return 'Err'
    else:
        print('Can walk!!!')
        self.death()
```

Comment: вообще в PyCharm хотя и выводится та же ошибка, но намек на настоящую ошибку виден - после `return` красным подчеркивается, т.е. python что-то ожидает, а дальше взглядом уже видно что `if/else` все закрыты и из блоков только `try` остается